# Why should i use JUST ONE solution for different projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I will create four projects each other works together.

- desktop program ( as User Interface for entering datas )
- web site ( for reporting )
- web service ( for connecting database - from desktop program and reporting portal )
- windows service ( for sending datas which are entered by users via desktop program to database )

Should i create one Visual Studio Solution which contains these four projects, or should i create different solutions for each of them?

What are the advantages of creating just one solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: If there is any relation between projects gather them below one solution - That relation is opinion-based ;).

Comment: there is no direct relation actually. i just call web service methods from web site and desktop program.

Comment: Do those four projects access each other, or access other projects included in the solution?

Comment: They will only communicate with web service methods. There will be no other connections.

Comment: How do you draw boundaries of your projects? As I don't know anything about vision and missions of your solution(s), I can't suggest anything about it. I want to say when you know vision and scope of your solution do it based on it ;).

Comment: it will be a HappyOrNot system. Users (our customers) will chose if they are Happy Or Not about our company. there are some windows tablets. desktop program which will be on these tablets will be the user interface . desktop program will save answers locally (sqlite) and send datas asyc via web service methods to database. and there will be another web site shows datas and reports etc.

Comment: As you are saying all four projects are some parts of one system that I can call it a [solution](http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/definition/solution), So let them under one solution ;).

Comment: actually my question is; why just one solution? is there any advantage or just for organizing projects?

Comment: what benefits you expect from having different solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here are some significant pros and cons which may affect you:

If you put them all in the same solution, it will be very easy to share code between them-- e.g. projects in a solution can reference another project assembly in the solution as a reference directly, making debugging very nice.   Nuget packages will share a common folder if they are shared, and you can see everything nicely at the same time.

However, if you these are programs that run independently but interact with each other, debugging is sometimes easier if they are in separate solutions, so separate copies of visual studio can be debugging the separate pieces simultaneously.

Comment: thank you for explaining sir.

Answer (score 1):

With one solution you will need to start only one VisualStudio instance, where you access code from different projects at once.

All possible refactorings(renaming, signature changing etc) can be easily done when you using one solution. With different solution you will never know if you remove/rename some code used by project from another solution.

You will be able to build all projects at once. Execute all possible unit and integration tests (if you have such)